# C# Timestamps are recorded as Hour Endings and DST is causing issues. Any ideas?

Tags: c#, .net, time, dst

I work with data that is recorded as an "Hour Ending" value.  What I mean by that is that the value recorded at 2am is "what happened" between 1:00am-1:59am.  Here is what the data looks like in a tabular format file (the first three columns are date information):

```
YY MM DD HE1  HE2  HE3  HE4  HE5  HE6  HE7  HE8  HE9 ...
19 03 10 1000 1010 1045 1045 1040 1030 1010 1020 1025 ...
```

The issue we're having is that the HE3 column doesn't actually exist in this data because of DST.  We need some value there though so our solution was to just record twice whatever value comes next.  When using the data in C# most libraries delete the HE2 column because the timestamp for that column *is* the end of DST HE2 would be recorded as "2019-03-10T02:00".  We have this data for hundreds of nodes accross hundreds of timezones all with different DST rules.  Is there any C# library that supports an "Hour Ending" idea as far as time goes? If not can anyone think of any good solution for treating DST as if it happens an hour later than it actually does?

Comment: Is there any reason why you have to record this using local time at all? If you record everything using UTC instead, there won't be any DST to account for. You can always convert to local time when displaying a particular record. (Note that storing UTC isn't always the right solution, but for *historical* data as opposed to future data, it usually is.)

Comment: @JonSkeet that is a good point... The system I'm working on is 25 years old.  There is 25 years worth of data not recorded in UTC that we'd have to deal with.  I guess the question now is do we need a data overhaul where all these random files on a file system are converted to UTC.

Comment: That's likely to be something we can't really answer for you - it'll be a matter of estimating how much effort it will take to migrate the existing data (and anything that reads it), vs the ongoing cost of working with a data format that has this problem.

Comment: I think you will need to code a little bit to implement the right algorithm to do that. Take a look at the methods in the `TimeZoneInfo`class. There are a few methods that can deal with DST. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo?view=net-6.0

Comment: I'm not sure why you've got a `nodatime` tag by the way - there's no indication of using Noda Time within the question. Fundamentally this is more a *conceptual* problem than coding, to start with. If your data doesn't contain the information you need, that's a problem regardless of the framework used. (It's also unclear what you mean by "the HE3 column doesn't actually exist" - it would be really helpful if you could give a more concrete example of the actual problem.)